# Integrating Jhipster and Cucumber-JVM

Tags: java, spring, cucumber-jvm, jhipster

I am trying to integrate JHipster with Cucumber, that is: I want to write my tests using Gerkin DSL and execute it using Cucumber-JVM. I did good progress but now I am blocked with the following error message:

*No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined*

It seems all my beans are found by Cucumber-JVM, but I don't know why this bean not. I suspect it can be related to the way Jhispter is managing application configuration.
Cucumber-JVM has spring support in its configuration:

   `<context:component-scan base-package="com.jobvacancy"/>
   <context:annotation-config/>`

Am I missing something? 
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Sure, but it is quite long to paste it here, so I put it here: https://gist.github.com/nicopaez/7093ee81d48871bea8be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: this question is now deprecated because since version 2.23.0 jhipster comes with built-in support for cucumber.